# Connecting OSX + Python + MSSQL

Tags: python, osx-mavericks, pyodbc, freetds

I'm new to Python development and I am trying to set up a Python/Flask project on my Mac (Mavericks) to connect with an MSSQL server via pyodbc + freetds + unixodbc.

**I can connect and query the server using `isql` and `osql`, but I can't get pyodbc to connect.**

How I got isql and osql working:

- install python via brew: `brew install python`
- installed pip and virtualenv
- install unixodbc via brew: `brew install unixodbc`
- install freetds via brew: `brew install freetds --with-unixodbc`
- update freetds.conf, odbc.ini (odbc.ini pointing directly to driver)
- update permissions on lib to make executable: `chmod 554 /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so`

At this point, I can successfully connect. Now, for the pyodbc part...

- from within my virtualenv, install pyodbc `sudo pip install pyodbc`

Depending on my connection string, I get some variation of this error:

```
DBAPIError: (Error) ('IM002', '[IM002] [iODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified. Driver could not be loaded (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') None None
```

It looks like it's trying to use iODBC instead of unixODBC, which is probably my first problem.

**How can I get pyodbc to use unixODBC?**

Answer (score 2):

For anyone trying to figure this out, I got it to work my using pymssql instead of pyodbc.